# ValueError Exception is raised for a definition which was working fine earlier

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I have some deployed functions in Google Cloud Functions. They were working fine so far, but now ValueError exception is raised. What can be the reason?

I have tried to rearrange the code without the try: block, but than its only crashes.

```
def bws_func(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    request_args = request.args

    try:
        lat = float(request_json['lat'])
        lon = float(request_json['lon'])
        if type(lat) == int or type(lat) == float or type(lon) == int or type(lon) == float:
            if lat < 89 and lat > -89 and lon < 180 and lon > -180:
                _bws = bws(float(lat),float(lon))
                return jsonify(_bws), 200
            else:
                return jsonify({"Error": "latitude and/or longitude is not valid"}), 400
        else:
            return jsonify({"Error": "latitude or longitude is non integer or float"}), 400
    except ValueError:
        return jsonify({"Error": "input cannot be converted to float"}), 400
```

The proper response used to be a JSON object like below:

```
{
  "estimated_3sec_gust": {
    "100_recurrence": 38.84864760491245,
    "10y_recurrence": 33.672778503723734,
    "25y_recurrence": 36.17428872168459,
    "50y_recurrence": 37.63056054611294
  }
}
```

```
Date: Wed, 29 May 2019 04:17:38 GMT
Server: Wolfram Cloud
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-GeneratedFrom: Generated from the Wolfram Cloud: http://www.wolfram.com/cloud
X-Terms-of-Use: Terms of use: http://www.wolfram.com/legal/terms/wolfram-cloud.html
X-Data-Source-Information: Data source information: http://wolfram.com/knowledgebase/source-information
content-disposition: inline
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Python code for the network call.

```py
def bws_func(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    request_args = request.args

    try:
        lat = float(request_json['lat'])
        lon = float(request_json['lon'])
        if type(lat) == float and type(lon) == float:
            if lat < 89 and lat > -89 and lon < 180 and lon > -180:
                _bws = windfinder(lat,lon)
                return _bws, 200
            else:
                return jsonify({"Error": "latitude and/or longitude is not valid"}), 400
        else:
            return jsonify({"Error": "latitude or longitude is non integer or float"}), 400
    except ValueError:
        return jsonify({"Error": "input cannot be converted to float"}), 400
```

Comment: What is the `ValueError`? Please include the entire stack trace.

Comment: @DustinIngram , thanks for your question. It produces the following error: Failed to export to JSON for input:
{"site_location" -> {"Lat" -> 46, "Lon" -> 18}, "weather_station" -> {"location" -> {"lat" -> $Failed[[1]], "lon" -> $Failed[[2]]}, "country" -> CommonName["Country"], "name" -> $Failed, "elevation" -> QuantityMagnitude[$Failed], "distance" -> QuantityMagnitude[$Failed], "membership" -> CommonName[$Failed], "data_from" -> DateValue[Take[$Failed, 1], "Year"], "data_until" -> DateValue[Take[$Failed, -1], "Year"], "yearly_maxima" -> QuantityMagnitude[$Failed["Values"]]}}

Comment: Strage enough, that in Google Chrome I am able to paste the full URL (CloudObject + params) and returns a proper answer. But with Postman or Insomnia it returns always with errors.

Comment: I have updated the post body with additional info about the HTTP response.

Comment: That doesn't look like a `ValueError`, that looks like a javascript error?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was confusing with the ValueError. The reason I stated on that way because I implemented in a cloud function, where I have a block of exception to be raised and the ValueError is one of them. Pls see the post body to be updated with this block of Python code.